# No jquery intellisense in scratchpad for firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, scratchpad

Scratchpad shows the properties of the `$` object when clicking the inspect button but does not provide intellisense when I type something like `$(".something")`. followed by ctrl+space.

Any suggestions for getting this to work ?

Firefox 32.0 with firebug 2.03, firebug autocompleter 1.4.1, firequery 1.4.1